# R filter table with mapping table to reduce NA values

Tags: r, select, filter, apply, na

I would like to filter a table bsp1

```
g <- factor(c("Company 1", "Company 2", "Company 3", "Company 4", "Company 5"))
w <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c"))
x <- c(28, 18, 25, NA, 21)
y <- c(80, NA, 74, 101, NA)
z <- c(170, 174, 183, NA, 185)
bsp1 <- data.frame(g, w, x, y, z)
colnames(bsp1) <- c("Company", "Sector", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
rm(w, x, y, z)
bsp1

#    Company Sector Item 1 Item 2 Item 3
# 1 Company 1      a     28     80    170
# 2 Company 2      b     18     NA    174
# 3 Company 3      c     25     74    183
# 4 Company 4      a     NA    101     NA
# 5 Company 5      c     21     NA    185
```

based on a mapping table bsp2

```
sector <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
a <- c(1, 1, 1)
b <- c(NA, 1, NA)
c <- c(NA, NA, 1)
bsp2 <- data.frame(sector, a, b, c)
colnames(bsp2)  <- c("Sector", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
bsp2

#   Sector Item 1 Item 2 Item 3
# 1      a      1     NA     NA
# 2      b      1      1     NA
# 3      c      1     NA      1
```

the filter rule should be:
For each sector in bsp2 for which the item is not NA, the rows in bsp1 from the respective sector with NA in the item should be removed.

The desired outcome looks therefore like bsp3

```
bsp3 <- bsp1[c(1, 3, 5),]
bsp3

#    Company Sector Item 1 Item 2 Item 3
# 1 Company 1      a     28     80    170
# 3 Company 3      c     25     74    183
# 5 Company 5      c     21     NA    185
```

Company 2 was dropped, as item 2 is required for b. Line 5 was not dropped as item 2 is not required for sector 3.

I thought about an apply function for all sectors over bsp1 with a vector of the relevant columns derived with following function for the vector.

```
a <- !is.na(bsp2[1,])
a <- which(a==c("TRUE"))
```

Unfortunately in the filter test of one vector I have a problem that b is interpreted as a Matrix.

```
b <- is.na(bsp1[, a]) 
c <- which(b==c("TRUE"))
reduced2016b <- data2013[-c,]
```

Even if I set up the vector manually, the filter result is not how I expect it.
Would be great if anyone has an idea to solve this problem. Also partial steps would help me already.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very similar answer, to above, was just finishing it when it was being posted.

you may want to define your data frames like so

```
    bsp1 <- data.frame(Company=factor(c("Company 1", "Company 2", "Company  3", "Company 4", "Company 5")),
                       Sector=factor(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c")),
                       Item1=c(28, 18, 25, NA, 21), 
                       Item2=c(80, NA, 74, 101, NA),
                       Item3= c(170, 174, 183, NA, 185))
```

and

```
    bsp2 <- data.frame(Sector=factor(c("a", "b", "c")), 
               Item1=c(1, 1, 1), 
               Item2=c(NA, 1, NA), 
               Item3=c(NA, NA, 1))
```

then melt and merge bsp1 and bsp2

```
    bsp1m <- melt(bsp1,id.vars=c("Company","Sector"))

    bsp2m <- melt(bsp2,id.vars="Sector", value.name = "flag") 

    bsp3m <- merge(bsp1m,bsp2m,by=c("Sector","variable"))
```

and finally subset bsp1 based on for where you have an NA in bsp1m and a 1 in bsp2m

```
    bsp3 <- bsp1[!bsp1$Company %in% bsp3m$Company[is.na(bsp3m$value) & !is.na(bsp3m$flag)],]
```

Comment: This is not similar to mine...it's exactly the same as mine

Comment: "*a very similar answer, to above, was just finishing it when it was being posted*" well, usually, when that happens (and it happens a lot), people just sigh, don't post,and upvote the other answer...

Comment: Anyway, apart from it being similar to or the same as another answer, generally it's best to make comments like that ("just finishing when...") down here in the comments. The body of the answer should mostly pertain directly to answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `melt` both data frames, `merge` by Sector and variable, and find which companies have `NA` for `value.x` and not `NA` for `value.y`, i.e.

```
library(reshape2)
new_df <- merge(melt(bsp1), melt(bsp2), by = c('Sector', 'variable'))
ind <- as.character(new_df$Company[is.na(new_df$value.x) & !is.na(new_df$value.y)])
bsp1[!bsp1$Company %in% ind,]

#    Company Sector Item 1 Item 2 Item 3
#1 Company 1      a     28     80    170
#3 Company 3      c     25     74    183
#5 Company 5      c     21     NA    185
```